# String output to text file

Tags: java, string, file-io, io, output

Working on a Java program that will determine whether or not a word is a palindrome.  Got that working well enough, so now I have to add a detail where it prints to an output file.

Problem is, after an hour of looking, I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for a method of output where it will print the following:

```
testString" is/is not a palindrome."
```

where testString is the original string input, so if the string were "Race car" it would print:

```
Race car is a palindrome.
```

I've attempted to use the code below as a print code, but it turns up an error when I put (testString " is a palindrome.") after it.  Can anyone offer a solution?

The code:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt"); // Initializer
out.println(text); //Printer to output file
```

Comment: Can you post the exact code that errors and the stack trace please

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the `+` to concatenate the two strings. Also, you should probably call PrintWriter using a file instead of just the filename, so if you get a File Not Found Exception or something, it will be more clear.

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/directory/file.txt");
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
printWriter.println(testString + " is a palindrome.");
```

Comment: Any imports that I have to do with it?  Or is java.io.* all I need?

Comment: You're just going to need: 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
Also, don't forget the + to concat the 2 strings..

Answer (score 0):

You should use   `out.close();` after those two lines.

```
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("D:\\test.txt"); // Initializer
    out.println(str+" is palindrome");
    out.close();
```

This is working fine.

Or you can use following way too

```
    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\test.txt")); 
    bw.append(str+" is palindrome");
    bw.newLine();
    bw.close();
```

Comment: If I close it and reopen it (it's part of a loop), won't it overwrite everything?

Comment: @TreyBrumley then close it out side the loop.

Comment: Done.

Now my initializer is turning up "Exception type FileNotFoundException."  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have the function that is a palindrome return a boolean and then check it with an if statement.

```
String s = "Test String";

if(isPalindrome(s))
  out.println(s + " is a palindrome.");
else
  out.println(s + " is not a palindrome.");

out.close();
```